# If $f(2x-3) = 4x-2$, then what is $f(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this statement:

> If $f(2x-3) = 4x-2,$ the function $f(x)$ is ...?

My attempt was:

Move the function $3$ units to the left

$f(2x) = 4(x+3) -2 = 4x+10$

Divide $x$ by $2$

$f(x) = 2x+10$

Verifiy $f(x) = 2x+10 \to f(2x) = 4x+10 \to f(2x-3) = 4(x-3)+10 = \underbrace{4x-2}_{f(2x-3)}$

But according to the  guide the correct answer is $2x+4$ and i don't know why. Thans in advance.

Comment: put $(x+3)/2$ instead of $x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is where you went wrong:

If $f(x)= $ [some expression involving $x$], then you can indeed say that $f(x+3)$ = [that expression with $x+3$ filled in for $x$

And, if you have $f(x-3)=$ [some expression involving $x$], then you can indeed say that $f(x)=$ [that expression with $x+3$ filled in for $x$]

So far so good.

But, all you have is that $f(\color{red}{2}x-3)=...$. If you want to 'shift' this, you will have to do this relative to $2x$ ... your mistake was to still treat this as if it was just $x$

What to do? Well, treat the $2x$ as a variable, i.e. Say $y=2x$, and rewrite the formula in terms of this $y$. So, in your case, we can say:

$4x-2=2y-2$

OK, and now we can do our normal shift:

$f(y-3)=2y-2$

And thus:

$f(y)=2(y+3)-2=2y+4$

Substituting $y=2x$ back:

$f(2x)=4x+4$

And hence

$f(x)=2x+4$

Answer (score 2):

Put $y=2x-3$. Then $x=(y+3)/2$. In particular
$$
f(y)=4x-2=4\left(\frac{y+3}{2}\right)-2=2(y+3)-2=2(y+2)
$$
as desired.

Comment: So, what step is wrong?

Comment: The first step. And the verification. If $f(x)=2x+10$, then $f(2x-3)=2(2x-3)+10=4x+4$.

Answer (score 1):

If $y=2x-3$, what is $x$? We have $x = {1 \over 2} (y+3)$.

If $x = {1 \over 2} (y+3)$, what is $4x-2$? We have $4x-2=2y+4$.

This will give $f(y)$ in terms of $y$.

Explicitly, $f(y) = 2y+4$.

Comment: So, what step is wrong?

Comment: When you moved $x$ to the left you made a mistake. Since the parameter is $2x-3$ you really want to move $x$ by ${ 3 \over 2}$. Then $2(x_{new}+{3 \over 2}) = 2 x_{new}$.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in\mathbb R$, then\begin{align}f(x)&=f\left(2\frac x2\right)\\&=f\left(2\left(\frac x2+\frac32\right)-3\right)\\&=4\left(\frac x2+\frac32\right)-2\\&=2x+4.\end{align}

Comment: So, what step is wrong?

Comment: The first step is wrong. From $f(2x-3)=4x-2$ you cannot deduce that $f(2x)=4(x+3)-2$.

Comment: So how it would look $f(2x-3)$ when I move it $3$ units to the left?

Comment: It would look like$$f\bigl(2(x+3)-3\bigr)=4(x+3)-2=4x+10.$$But this is not $f(2x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y$ equal to an expression that will make $2y-3=x$ so that we can have $f(x)$.

This can be done if $y=\frac{x}{2}+1.5$

Plug $y$ in:

$f(2y-3)=4y-2$ and substitute the value of $y$ in terms of $x$:

$f(2(\frac{x}{2}+1.5)-3)=f(x)=4(\frac{x}{2}+1.5)-2=2x+4$

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer:

Let $y=2x-3$.  Then $f(y)=4x-2=2(2x-3)+4=2y+4.$

Where you went wrong:

If $f(2x-3)=4x-2=2(2x)-2$, then $f(2x)=2(2x+3)-2=4x+4.$

Answer (score 1):

Since the argument and output are linear, we can try to *extract* $2x-3$ from $4x-2$ through arithmetic means.

\begin{align}
f(\color{red}{2x-3})&=4x-2\\
&=4x\color{blue}{-6+6}-2\\
&=2(\color{red}{2x-3})+4
\end{align}

Therefore, $f(x)=2x+4$ as required.